# Azure Cli - How to show API's operation backend (HTTPs endpoint) infos

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I'm trying to display the backend base-url info of an operation's API in my apim instance, i can achieve my goal with the Azure Powershell Module command:

```
Get-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $mycontextvar -ApiId "myapiid" -OperationId "myoperationid" -Subscription "mysub" | Select-Xml -XPath '/policies/inbound/set-backend-service' | ForEach-Object { $_.Node."base-url" }
```

However, i want to display it with an azure cli command. I tried with

```
az apim api operation list --api-id myapiid --resource-group myrg --service-name myservname --subscription mysub
```

and

```
az apim api list --resource-group myrg --service-name myservname --subscription mysub
```

without results.

I should take into consideration the `az policy` or the `az network` commands but i don't know how to start to use them to retrieve this info and, once i saw the documentation, i don’t even know if they can help me.
'
Which Azure CLI command should i use to gather the backend base-url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do until the GET policy operation is available in CLI:

1. get operation **id** / **URL** with `az apim api operation show --api-id myapi --operation-id myop -g myrg -n myapim`
2. you will see an `id` like `"id": "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-5678-90ab-cdef12345678/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/myapim/apis/myapi/operations/myop",`
3. mix with policy **GET** operation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/api-operation-policy/get into

```
az rest --method get --url "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/12345678-1234-5678-90ab-cdef12345678/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/myapim/apis/myapi/operations/myop/policies/policy?api-version=2019-12-01"
```

which should give you the policy.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: thanks for the vote! - maybe phrase your question more exactly "How to extract API's operation backend (HTTP endpoint) from a policy with Azure CLI"